# rails - I ran "rake db:drop" by mistake. How could I restore my all data?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

Sadly.. I blew up all my data by running "rake db:drop".
And How could I restore all the data that my website had?

Please Help..

Comment: Do you have backups anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have working backups, your only option is going to be forensic recovery (very expensive, no guarantee of success).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I still have a question. Where developers  normally do database backup? Are database programs such as mysql, sqllite3 etc provide data backup service??  I ask this question because I'm not developer..

Comment: There are many backup tools and approaches available. For MySQL there is mysldump and xtrabackup. Of you can use snapshotsl based backups. What you end up using will depend on your server and cloud platform.